# LittleEndian - Validação do método matemático utilizado

Tags: matemática

Eu me deparei com um bloco de código que indicava, nos comentários, uma operação LittleEndian 32 bits.

As entradas são:

**buf = array de bytes**

```
buf[38] = 29
buf[39] = 153
buf[40] = 125
buf[41] = 12

sum1 = buf[41] * 256;
sum2 = sum1 + buf[40];
sum3 = sum2 * 256;
sum4 = sum3 + buf[39];
sum5 = sum4 * 256;
sum6 = sum5 + buf[38] ;
```

Eu não consegui entender o motivo pelo qual a pessoa decidiu somar o resultado da soma1:

```
sum1 = buf[41] * 256;
```

com com o valor do buf[40] e fazer, na sequência, a multiplicação por 256.

Isso seria de fato uma operação LittleEndian ou talvez a pessoa está aplicando outro método matemático neste cenário?

Comment: Em binário sob uma perspectiva BigEndian fazer `n * 256` é o mesmo que `n <<< 8` então o código preenche os primeiros oito bits de um double word e o desloca oito bits em sentido ao MSB. Sem informar em qual linguagem está sendo realizada a operação não possível informar se há processo ou procedimento mais eficiente para realizar a tarefa.

Comment: Olá Augusto!
Obrigado pelas observações.
A linguagem utilizada é o C#